# Date picker not highlighting selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, datepicker

I am using Angular.js in MVC 5 web application. There is date picker in my web page.

**directive**

```
myApp.directive('datepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ProfileCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                ProfileCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
};});
```

**input tag**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dob" class="col-sm-4 control-label text-left">DOB</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <input type="text" datepicker name="dob" class="form-control" ng-model="models.DOB" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Every thing works fine.

[image]

But I am facing a issue, when I try to load the date value from database to textbox, the  date pickeris not highlight the selected date, and date picker dateformat is different than textbox. Please see the below image.

[image]

Comment: Have you intialized `datepicker` with format options? If yes then check the `6th Jan 2015` which will be selected. So basically you need to take care of the `format` when you set it to `datepicker`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. selected date is 1 Jun 2015. I am already set the format dateFormat: 'MM/dd/yyyy' in directive. but it's not working.

Comment: Then you might need to try solution suggested by @PrajapatiVikas to convert it into specified format before setting it to `datepicker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code to correct your date format and check,

```
    $scope.models.DOB=GetFormattedDate(models.DOB);
    function GetFormattedDate(dateString, replaceNullValue) {
         if (replaceNullValue == false && IsBlank(dateString)) {
           return "";
         }
        var dt = dateString != null ? new Date(dateString) : new Date();
        var d = dt.getDate();
        var dd = d < 10 ? "0" + d : d;
        var m = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        var mm = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
        var y = dt.getFullYear();
        return mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.I am using your method but the datepicker is not highlighted the existing value in date picker. I mean i try to hilight the database date value in blue colour in date picker.